# Bid random amount which is not less than in DB via cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I need to give a logic for automating the test case for the below scenario. But I am not sure about how to approach it.
I bid every time new random amount, and I need to give a condition that the random bidded amount should not be less than the last bidded amount in DB, if it is less than the amount in the system it should give me an alert etc. This is my approach:

```
 const minval = 100;
  const maxval = 100000;
  // divide by 100, then round down, then multiply by 100, e.g.: 1234 / 100 = 12.34, floor(12.34) = 12, 12 * 100 = 1200. Need these two steps because floor(1234) = 1234
  const placeBidAmount = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxval) / 100) * 100 + minval;
  // in response body we have price amount and that should be equal
  const listPrice = placeBidAmount;
  const vehicleId = "aaaa";
  const platformId = "xxx";
  const platformUserId = 0;[![enter image description here][1]][1]

it.only("place a bid on the selected auction", () => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${Cypress.env('apiHostForEndpoints')}/bid`,


      headers: {
        Authorization: Cypress.env("token"),
        "content-type": Cypress.env("contentType"),
      },  

      body: {
        id: vehicleId,
        bid: placeBidAmount,
        auctionPlatformId: platformId,
        auctionPlatformUserId: platformUserId,
      },

      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).should((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.eq(200);

      expect(res.body.id).eq(vehicleId);
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("id", vehicleId);
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("price", placeBidAmount);
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("winningBidPlatformId", platformId);
      expect(res.body.price).to.be.equal(listPrice);
      // assert
      //   .isNotNull(res.body.id, "is not null")
      //   .and.isNotNull(res.body.createdAt, "is not null");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why do you want to bid random amounts? That's a recipe for flaky tests and frustrating debugging.

Comment: My idea is to bid a random amount because we never know what amount the user will bid. Please give your suggestion my approach might be wrong

Comment: Don't know what amount _what_ user will bid?

Comment: yes, this is bidding app.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. This is a _test_, are you not in control of who's bidding what?

Comment: I need to test bidded amount. The system should not accept the amount which is less than the already bidded amount. This is what I need to test

Comment: I think what jonrsharpe is getting at is that bidding a _random_ amount will introduce flakiness, and a more surefire way to test this functionality would be to either mock the request's response and always use amounts above/below that, or to take the actual amount and use amounts slightly above/below that for your validation.